# GLMM with random correlation parameter converged, whereas the one without did not converge

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, covariance-matrix

I would like to fit a generalized linear mixed model with binary outcome using the glmer function. Currently I am using the data provided by the book from Heck, Thomas and Tabata (2012) - https://www.routledge.com/Multilevel-Modeling-of-Categorical-Outcomes-Using-IBM-SPSS/Heck-Thomas-Tabata/p/book/9781848729568.
In this context I wanted to vary the variance-covariance structure between the models. As Heck, Thomas and Tabata (2012) recommend, I wanted to start using a variance component structure as a simpler structure first and fit the same model using an unstructured variance-covariance structure in the next step.

This is the code I used for the variance component structure, which estimates variances for the random effects but assumes the covariance to be 0:

```
m1 <- glmer(readprof ~ female+lowses+minor+smallsch+schcomp+minor*schcomp+minor*smallsch
            +(1|schcode) + (0+minor|schcode),
            family = binomial(link = logit), data = HeckThomasTabata, nAGQ = 1)
```

I got the following warning messages:

```
m1<-glmer(readprof~female+lowses+minor+smallsch+schcomp+minor*schcomp+minor*smallsch+(1|schcode) + (0+minor|schcode),family = binomial(link = logit), data = HeckThomasTabata, nAGQ = 1)
Warning messages:
1: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
  unable to evaluate scaled gradient
2: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
  Model failed to converge: degenerate  Hessian with 1 negative eigenvalues
```

Then this is the code I used for the unstructured variance-covariance structure:

```
m2 <- glmer(readprof ~ female+lowses+minor+smallsch+schcomp+minor*schcomp+minor*smallsch
            +(1+minor|schcode),
            family = binomial(link = logit), data = HeckThomasTabata, nAGQ = 1)
```

And this model converged easily.

I am now wondering, why the model with the unstructured variance-covariance structure easily converges whereas the model with the variance components structure doesn't. I thought, the model with the easier structure (variance components) would be more likely to converge (see Heck et al., 2012) and the model with the more complex structure might struggle to converge, but what happened is just the opposite.

Can someone explain it to me?
Also - are the codes I used appropriate for what I intended to model?

Comment: The first thing I would try is a different optimizer.

Comment: `help("convergence")`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This is what I have been trying, but didn't get to a solution... m1<-glmer(readprof~female+lowses+minor+smallsch+schcomp+(1|schcode) + (0+minor|schcode),family = binomial(link = logit), data = HeckThomasTabata, nAGQ = 1, control=glmerControl(optimizer = c("bobyqa", "Nelder_Mead","optimx.nlminb","optimx.L-BFGS-B")))
I got the exact same warning messages. Is the code alright for trying different optimizers? If so, what do the warning messages mean? Apologize my lack of prior knowledge, I am very new to the topic and also working with R for the first time.

Comment: Maybe to add to it... I fitted the models in SPSS first (with PQL, which seems to be the only estimation method available in SPSS). However... using the variance components structure in SPSS worked out fine, whereas the model with an unstructured var-cov-structure wouldn't converge, which seemed plausible to me because of the increasing complexity. So I was very surprised when in R the model with the unstructured var-cov-structure converged but the model with variance components didn't. Any ideas how to deal with that issue in practice?